# printfn "%A" "c" using F#

Tags: f#, string-formatting

By running `printfn "%A" "c"`, I get `"c"`.

By running `printfn "%s" "c"`, I get `c`.

Why the difference? The same goes for `char`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `%A` specifier tries to hint at object types - the `"c"` is it trying to show it is a string.  When you do `%s` the compiler knows you want to print a string so it doesn't print the quotes

Answer (score 4):

Because `printfn "%A"` uses reflection, it displays results the same as values automatically printed out by F# Interactive. On the other hand, `%s` is for strings only, and it shows contents of strings.

The generic case of `"%s"` is `"%O"` when `ToString` methods are used. The `%A` specifier is slow, but helpful for structural types and types without overridden `ToString` methods.